# Android LibGDX Make Texture/Text "Touch to Start" blink

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I pretty much finished my LibGDX project and now I'm just adding user-friendliness.
I have a Texture (also placed in a sprite) that I would like to fade in and fade out repeatedly (NOT fast blinking). It's just rectangular funky-text that says "Touch to Start".

- I considered making an animation of 6 or so pictures with varying opacity and just keep changing slides. Is this the best way to go?
- I'm also looking for a libGDX effect that controls the transparency to avoid all the overhead and not make my animation choppy.

Can't think of any relevant code to add, Thanks for your help

[image]

EDIT

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(touchToStartImage, screenWidth / 2 - touchToStartImage.getWidth() / 2, screenHeight / 2 - touchToStartImage.getHeight() / 2);
    elapsed += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    blinkFontCache.setAlphas(Interpolation.fade.apply((elapsed / 0.01f) % 1f));
    blinkFontCache.draw(batch);
    blinkFontCache.translate(2f, 2f);
    batch.end();
```

I also defined `blinkFontCache = new BitmapFontCache(numberPrinter);` where numberPrinter is bitmapfont that is supposed to draw text. I've read the API guide for Interpolation and blinkFontCache, but unfortunately with the above I do not notice any change in the screen I have. Thanks

**SOLUTION**

EDIT with INTERPOLATION

```
    elapsed += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    touchToStartSprite.setAlpha(Interpolation.fade.apply((elapsed / FADE_TIME) % 1f));

    blinker.begin();
    touchToStartSprite.draw(batch);
    blinker.end();
```

EDIT with ACTIONS

definitions

```
text = new Image(highScoreImage);
        text.addAction(Actions.alpha(0));
        text.act(0);
        text.addAction(Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeIn(FADE_TIME), Actions.fadeOut(FADE_TIME))));
```

render()

```
    blinker.begin();
    text.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    text.draw(blinker, 1);
    blinker.end();
```

Comment: Are you using stage2d?

Comment: Oops sorry only Box2D that's good info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Image` class from scene2d, which is an actor that can take a texture region and gives you several methods that can be useful. Here's an implementation.

```
 Image text = new Image(clickToStartRegion);
 Float fadeTime = 1f;

 //...

 text.addAction(Actions.alpha(0)); //make the text transparent.
 text.act(0); //update the text once
 text.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeIn(fadeTime), Actions.fadeOut(fadeTime));

 //...

 text.act(deltaTime);

 //...

 text.draw(batch, 1);
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks so much! I need to play around with this some more because right now it only flashes once (I'll try to toss more of them under render()). But really the progress is relieving, cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Interpolation class for the alpha. Assuming you're using a Sprite to draw this:

```
private float elapsed;
private static final float FADE_TIME = 1f; //time between blinks

//...

elapsed += deltaTime;
sprite.setAlpha(Interpolation.fade.apply((elapsed / FADE_TIME) % 1f));

//...

spriteBatch.begin();
sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.end();
```

Comment: Sorry I was assuming you were using a BitmapFont to draw your text, but on rereading it I see that you are using a sprite. See edited answer.

Comment: I'm confused by the code you added since there is both a sprite and a font and you don't change the alpha of the sprite. And the font you have set to blink 100 times a second which will not look right.

Comment: Thanks, just for edu purposes I applied the change and now it does blink! As for the 100 times per second I was wondering if perhaps I did something stupid and maybe it was working but just at a speed I wouldn't notice

Comment: I appreciate this a lot, personally I think this is a more robust solution but I'm going to end up using scene2d since when it blinks, it fades in and fades out. Using this, it'll fade in and vanish and cycle back. I'm sure there would be a fix to this if I got clever with mods, however. Both answers are great and I will be using interpolation and actions more in the future, cheers!